# org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'generalservice' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

In my spring cloud gateway I get this error while execution of a get using webclient:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'generalservice' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 11 queries 
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://generalservice/user/ [DefaultWebClient]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
```

I think that I need some configuration in the application, in postman the request go well.

So, this is my configuration bean:

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://generalservice").build();
}
```

And the web client in my custom filter:

```
 return webClient.get().uri("/user/", email).headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(authBearer)).retrieve().bodyToMono
                    (String.class).flatMap(s -> {
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            });
```

How can I fix the error?

thanks in advance!